# Locking scroll position when lazy loading in infinite scroll (scroll up)

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I have a conversation / WhatsApp like feature in my application. Newest messages are at the bottom, oldest are at the top.

When I scroll near the top of the messages it automatically loads more in BUT I want to keep the scroll position where it is.  I have created a directive that does this but the problem is it flickers. What seems to happen is the new messages get loaded and the scroll position is reset to the top. Then my directive kicks in and resets the scroll position to where it was.  So it works, but doesnt look great.

Does anyone have any clues how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="conversation-scroll-container" scroll-lock="{{ vm.isLoading }}">
```

VM (load messages function):

```
return this.messageService
    .getMessages(conversation, dates)
    .then(data => {
        this.selectedConversation.applyNewMessages(data);

        return data;
    })
    .finally(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
    });
```

And finally the directive (its in TS):

```
export class ScrollLockDirective implements angular.IDirective {
    public restrict = "A";
    private scrollLock = false;
    private scrollLockOffset = 0;

    constructor(private $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService) { }

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($timeout: angular.ITimeoutService) => new ScrollLockDirective($timeout);

        directive.$inject = ["$timeout"];

        return directive;
    }

    public link = (scope: angular.IScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: angular.IAttributes) => {

        attributes.$observe("scrollLock", () => {

            if (attributes["scrollLock"] === "true") {
                this.scrollLock = true;
            }
            else {
                this.doLockScroll(element);
                this.scrollLock = false;
            }
        });

        element.bind("scroll", () => {
            this.doLockScroll(element);
        });

        scope.$on("$destroy", () => {
            element.unbind("scroll");
        });
    }

    private doLockScroll(element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery) {

        if (this.scrollLock) {
            this.$timeout(() => {
                element.scrollTop(element[0].scrollHeight - this.scrollLockOffset);
            });
        } else {
            this.scrollLockOffset = element[0].scrollHeight - element.scrollTop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same flicker problem when adding elements above but want to retain scroll position. I guess the main issue is that we need to let angular render the DOM before we know the height which we need to adjust for. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem as you and i also tried to set scrollTop position and etc., but solution is quite simple: you just need render only new items, instead rerender all items.